# cpanel error Altered RPMs found on server

Tags: cpanel, whm, centos6.5

I have cpanel installed on my dedicated server. I am receiving the error below frequently:

```
Problems were detected with cPanel-provided files which are RPM controlled.
If you did not make these changes intentionally, you can correct them by running:

> /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/check_cpanel_rpms --fix

The following RPMs are missing from your system:
exim-4.82-4.cp1136
```

When i run /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/check_cpanel_rpms --fix, i get this

```
root@server1 [~]# /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/check_cpanel_rpms --fix
[20141009.104321]   
[20141009.104321]   Problems were detected with cPanel-provided files which are RPM controlled.
[20141009.104321]   If you did not make these changes intentionally, you can correct them by     running:
[20141009.104321]   
[20141009.104321]   > /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/check_cpanel_rpms --fix
[20141009.104321]   The following RPMs are missing from your system:
[20141009.104321]   exim-4.82-4.cp1136
[20141009.104326]   Removing 0 broken rpms: 
[20141009.104326]   rpm: no packages given for erase
[20141009.104327]   Downloading http://httpupdate.cpanel.net/RPM/11.36/centos/6/x86_64/rpm.md5
[20141009.104327]   exim-4.82-4.cp1136.x86_64.rpm already downloaded
[20141009.104328]   Hooks system enabled
[20141009.104328]   Checking for and running RPM::Versions 'pre' hooks for any RPMs about to be    installed
warn [check_cpanel_rpms] program "/scripts/preeximup" is not executable
[20141009.104328]   All required 'pre' hooks have been run
[20141009.104328]   No RPMS need to be uninstalled
[20141009.104328]   Installing new rpms: exim-4.82-4.cp1136.x86_64.rpm
[20141009.104328]   error: Failed dependencies:
[20141009.104328]       sendmail = 8.14.4-8.el6 is needed by (installed) sendmail-devel-8.14.4-8.el6.x86_64
[20141009.104328] W Error Code: 1
[20141009.104328] E The following possible errors were detected while installing RPMs:
[20141009.104328] E Failed dependencies
[20141009.104328]   The Administrator will be notified to review this output when this script completes
[20141009.104328]   Checking for and running RPM::Versions 'post' hooks for any RPMs just installed
warn [check_cpanel_rpms] program "/scripts/posteximup" is not executable
[20141009.104328]   All required 'post' hooks have been run
```

What do i do to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, no one in the world knows much about this. I would like to stop getting these notifications, after making config changes. I don't want to run the fix option, in case it restores the configs to defaults. Looking at the output of the fix program listed above, it says if the changes were intention run... the fix program. Does running the program once just give info and running it again reset the comparison file? If so, how do you reset the config files if you didn't intentionally change some files? I've Googled extensively and the results are loaded with pages that won't serve, most seem to be from a 2013 update that trigger the message on a lot of servers.

Also, I wonder if the config changes that I made will be undone the next update?